# pythonのclass継承について

Tags: python, python3

Pythonのクラスの勉強をしていてクラス継承で引っかかり苦戦しているのでお力を貸して頂けないでしょう？

```
class Shape:
    squs = []
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.squs = squs

class Square(Shape):
    def go_list(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        return self.squs.append(self.width)

s1 = square(20, 20)
print(s1.go_list())
s2 = square(10, 10)
print(s2.go_list())
```

**結果が最初は[20]になって次に[20,10]になるようにしたいです。**

Shapeクラスで作ったリストsqusに継承させて使いたいのですが、うまく行きません。
どのように変更したら良いでしょうか？

Comment: プリント文でs1,s2のgo_listを表示するようにしていますが、Sは大文字ではないでしょうか。後squsですが、self.squs=self.squsとしないと私の環境ではエラーになりました。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。sは小文字に変更しました。このselfとは一体どういう意味なのでしょうか？selfをつけたらエラーがなくなりました。

Comment: selfの意味については別の質問なので、別の質問を提起していただくことになりそうです。selfは、読んで字のごとく、自分自身という意味で、クラスが自分自身のメソッドや変数を、自分で参照できるためにつける目印みたいなものと思っておいてください。基本書には必ず説明してあると思いますから、じっくりと読み、またコードの関係性などから意味を推測するため、今後の勉強の継続を応援します。エラーを繰り返しながらよく考えた方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど。それはそういう意味であることもありますが、クラスの初期化は、データを消すことではなくて、一番最初に定義しておくもの。というような感じですね。コードを実行するごとに、クラスで一番最初に実行されますから、データをいったん消すのも消さないのも同じことですから、そういう意味でもいいかもしれません。

Comment: ごめんなさい。新しく質問作った方が良いと思いコメントを消してしまいました。"初期化と聞くとイメージでは中に入ってるデータが消えてなくなってしまいそうなのですが初期化して渡すのですか？"

Comment: 疑問点をもう少しまとめて、質問を作るのもいいですが、似た質問がないかその前に検索をしておくとよさそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Shape:
    squs = []
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.squs = self.squs

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self,w,h):
        super().__init__(w,h)

    def go_list(self):
        self.squs.append(self.width)

        return self.squs

S1 = Square(20, 20)
print(S1.go_list())
S2 = Square(10, 10)
print(S2.go_list())
```

これでいかがでしょうか。

**解説**
コメントにも書いた通り、若干のシンタックスエラーが発見されました。それを治したうえでなのですが、

**appendの落とし穴**
一番大きなポイントは、`append`後の値をreturnで返してしまった事です。
`append`メソッドの戻り値は、常に`None`となります。
ですから、`append`した後のリストを戻り値として渡しましょう。
**クラス変数**
`squs`は、クラス変数として定義されていますが、これは例えば、
`Shape.squs`として、クラスの名前.変数で参照可能な変数という意味です。
インスタンスを生成しなくても参照できる。という意味です。しかし、インスタンス無しで参照できるといっても、どのクラスに属しているかを、頭につける必要があります。
ですから、それを内部で参照するには、やはり、`self.squs`としなければならないようです。
**継承後の__init__とsuper()**
これは、継承前のクラスの初期化メソッドを実行するものです。
継承前のクラス`Shape`は、引数として、`w`,`h`を渡しています。
これがそもそもなければ、`self.width`,`self.height`に値を渡せませんから、
`__init__(self,w,h)`として、`super()`の後に、`w`,`h`を値渡しするようにしています。

Answer (score 0):

`squs` はクラスの属性なので、`Shape.squs.append(self.width)` にして、`def return_squs(self):` を追加する で、どうでしょうか。

```
class Shape:
    squs = []
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        Shape.squs.append(self.width)
    def return_squs(self):
        return Shape.squs

class Square(Shape):
    def go_list(self):
        Shape().__init__(self)


S1 = Square(20, 20)
print(S1.return_squs())
S2 = Square(10, 10)
print(S2.return_squs())
```

Comment: こちらのコードでもうまく行きます！superを使わないでも継承できるのですね！